# Reading properties file in cucumber step definition using selenium-webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

**Scenario :-**

- Automation of web application using cucumber & selenium webdriver

**Data :-**

- Saved xpath of web elements in properties file.

**Issue :-**

How to read xpaths mentioned in properties file in global step_definitions keywords Given , When & Then ?

Comment: do you want to read the xpath from properties file in feature files or step definition files?

Comment: from step definition file

Answer (score 0):

java has inbuilt mechanism to read property file.

Comment: I know about inbuilt mexhanism...I want sample code to understand it. In cucumber step definition package->step definiton class , I want to read data from properties file in keyword functions namely given , when , then

Comment: a simple good search will let you know how to read property file in java. include that in glue code and then call them in your step definition.